# Post to remote API from Azure function

Tags: azure, function

I have a simple Azure function I wrote in my Visual Studio instance and it receives messages and sends them on to a local POSTMAN instance I have running, here's how the function looks:

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

            var relay = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);

            var postData = new StringContent(relay, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var authHeader = req.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
            log.LogInformation($"Headers: {req.Headers["Authorization"]}");
            log.LogInformation($"Data: {postData.ReadAsStringAsync()}");

            using(var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(req.Headers["SpecialURI"]);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", authHeader);

                var result = await client.PostAsync("", postData);
                var response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var returnResult = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent(response, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                };

                return returnResult;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above function receives a POST and this post contains the body along with authorization and a special URI where I want it to forward the data. This function works perfectly in my local instance but when I try to send the data to a remote API then I get an OK status and there's no data sent to my remote API instance. Do I need to open the connection to the remote API somehow or what am I missing?

Comment: Does the function need to be published in order to post to remote API's?

Comment: you are not checking the StatusCode of the .PostAsync() result anywhere, that might be a clue to what is happening.  Your API is always returning HttpStatusCode.OK even if the post to the remote api fails so you might want to fix that.